# Firebase Realtime database rules "Unknown variable 'request'."

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image]

Does anyone know why I can't use this snippet from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#realtime-database_2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like a documentation mistake because in Firestore you would write `request.auth.uid` while in the RTDB you just write `auth.uid`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add comma after :
".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"